# sending Image through GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I used this code for sending images through GCM but there is an error in this code:

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String uriStr = intent.getStringExtra(FIELD_MESSAGE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse(uriStr));

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(970970, notification);
}
```

Comment: can you post error stack ?

Comment: see this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840282/load-image-from-url-in-notification-android

Comment: you can't send image through GCM. you can send image address. but it wont allow you to send image. cause its payload size is fixed to 4kb i think.

Comment: what is that error can you show us ??

Comment: the error is that I cannot send Image 

I need help
if cannot send through gcm then any other possible way.