# Image Not Showing with Push Notification Text

Tags: android, notifications

In my case, Firebase text push notification is working fine but image not displays in push notification please tell me what may be the possible cause and also please rectify my code because i'm new on android studio.

MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

```js
package com.iaritoppers.FirebaseService;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
import com.iaritoppers.Config.Config;
import com.iaritoppers.Helper.NotificationHelper;
import com.iaritoppers.R;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.squareup.picasso.Target;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    Target target = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                showNotificationWithImageLevel26 (bitmap);
            else 
            showNotificationWithImage(bitmap);

        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }
    };

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void showNotificationWithImageLevel26(Bitmap bitmap) {
        NotificationHelper helper = new NotificationHelper(getBaseContext());

        Notification.Builder builder = helper.getchannel(Config.title,Config.message,bitmap);
        helper.getManager().notify(0,builder.build() );
    }

    private void showNotificationWithImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle style = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        style.setSummaryText(Config.message);
        style.bigPicture(bitmap);

        Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSound)
                .setStyle(style);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());


    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.getData() !=null)
            getImage(remoteMessage);
    }

    private void getImage(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Config.message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        Config.title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        if (remoteMessage.getData() != null) {
            Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                            .load(remoteMessage.getData().get("image"))
                            .into(target);
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

MyFirebaseService.java

```js
package com.iaritoppers.FirebaseService;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

public class MyFirebaseService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();
        sendNewTokenToServer (FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
    }

    private void sendNewTokenToServer(String token) {
        Log.d("EDMTTToken",token);
    }
}
```

NotificationHelper.java

```js
package com.iaritoppers.Helper;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.iaritoppers.Config.Config;
import com.iaritoppers.R;

public class NotificationHelper extends ContextWrapper {
    private static final String EDMT_CHANNEL_ID = "com.iaritoppers.EDMTDev";
    private static final String EDMT_CHANNEL_Name = "EDMTDev";
    private NotificationManager manager;

    public NotificationHelper(Context base) {
        super(base);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            createChannel();
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void createChannel() {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(EDMT_CHANNEL_ID,EDMT_CHANNEL_Name,NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.enableLights(true);
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);

        getManager().createNotificationChannel(channel);


    }

    public NotificationManager getManager() {
        if (manager == null)
        manager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        return manager;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public Notification.Builder getchannel(String title, String body, Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        Notification.Style style = new Notification.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmap);

        Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        return new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(),EDMT_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSound)
                .setStyle(style);
    }
}
```

Config.java

```js
package com.iaritoppers.Config;

public class Config {
    public static String message="";
    public static String title="";
}
```

Manifest.xml

```js
<service android:name=".FirebaseService.MyFirebaseService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".FirebaseService.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Comment: If By image you mean the large rectangle image ?  See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840282/load-image-from-url-in-notification-android).

Answer (score 0):

just add this code in MyFirebaseMessagingService file ..
Convert your Notification image to Bitmap ..

```
String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                    .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                            .bigPicture(bitmap))
                    .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_SMALL)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_name),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
        channel.setShowBadge(true);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.enableLights(true);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

complete Push Notification code ::

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();
Bitmap bitmap;

@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    Log.e("NEW_TOKEN", s);
    storeRegIdInPref(s);

}

private void storeRegIdInPref(String token) {
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("regId", token);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(remoteMessage.getNotification().getImageUrl().toString());

        sendNotification_withImage(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage,bitmap);

    }
}

public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return bitmap;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }
}


private void sendNotification_withImage(String messageBody, RemoteMessage remoteMessage, Bitmap bitmap) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                    .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                            .bigPicture(bitmap))
                    .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_SMALL)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    notificationBuilder.setDefaults(DEFAULT_SOUND | DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_name),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
        channel.setShowBadge(true);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.enableLights(true);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}