# Load remote image to NotificationCompat MessagingStyle Message SetData in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications, android-notification-bar, android-notification.mediastyle

I am trying to load image from a remote url in `NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.Message.setData()` method.

Code is like this

```
val senderImg = Picasso.with(this).load(senderAvatar).get()

val sndr = Person.Builder()
                .setName(senderName)
                .setIcon(IconCompat.createWithBitmap(senderImg))
                .build()

bldr = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)

val imageUri = Uri.parse(imageUrl)

mssg = NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.Message(
                    msg,
                    Date().time, sndr
                ).setData("image/", "https://i.imgur.com/wrv4Ngp.jpg")



NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle(sndr)
                .addMessage(mssg)
                .setBuilder(bldr)


NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, bldr.build())
```

But the image is not displaying. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need to download the image first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24866080/2894324